# Arduino Http Post with JSON

Tags: json, post, arduino, http-post

I'm trying to post a json data via Arduino.When ı'm trying to this code.ı will send a json data with QueryString.If ı try this code the server answer me with Wrong QueryString format.Which mean is ı'm connected to server and server got my data.

```
 if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
Serial.println("connected");
// Make a HTTP request:
client.println("POST /URL?query=jsondata HTTP/1.1");
client.println("Host: **.**.**.**");
client.println("Connection: close\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
client.print("Content-Length: ");
client.println(PostData.length());
client.println();
client.println(PostData);
```

}

But My Main Plan is send my json data with querystring.If ı Try this code ;

```
client.println("POST /URL?query={request:{Header:{Username:kullaniciAdi,Password:123456},Item:{Serial:ABC123QWE,Data:100, DateOn:23/11/1986 15:45:24}}} HTTP/1.1");
```

I get a HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.

Anyone Has a any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your URI contains spaces and may contain other characters to confuse the format of the post request. You need to encode these characters.

As far as I can tell, the Arduino standard libraries do not include any form of urlEncode method, which is common in other languages and libraries, so you will either have to create your own or look for one.

Your resulting code would be something like:

```
String request = "/URL?query={request:{Header:{Username:kullaniciAdi,Password:123456},Item:{Serial:ABC123QWE,Data:100, DateOn:23/11/1986 15:45:24}}}";
String encRequest = uriEncode(request); // need to write your own method for this...
String post = "POST " + encRequest + " HTTP/1.1");
client.println( post);
```

Some discussion on creating a uriEncode function is on the [Arduino Forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,99538.0.html) and there also appears to be a [working method on hardwarefun.com](http://hardwarefun.com/tutorials/url-encoding-in-arduino)

Comment: do ı have to include any library for using Var and encodeURIComponent ?

Comment: My apologies, I thought this was a javascript issue I'm amending my answer to give a more  Arduino centric response